# Entity Framework - DBContext Equality

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext, equality

I've inherited a bit of code where an existing DBContext is assigned to a local variable as so:

```
using(var context = new DBContext())
{
  try
  {
     ...

     var localContext = context;
     MethodThatAddsStuffToContext(localContext);

     ...
   }
    catch etc. etc.

  context.SaveChanges();
}
```

My question is: I know that different contexts will persist their own changes and that they will only be picked up by other contexts after a save, but:

1. Do Contexts use Reference equality, meaning that `context` and `localContext` above will share the same additions, and saving one will commit changes on the other?
2. If I have two existing separate contexts, and I save one, will the changes be automatically picked up in the new context on any future query, or does a context "cache" at the point that it is created (pretty sure the answer to this is the former, but just want to clarify)?
3. Is the code snippet above bad practice? I can't think of any circumstance where it would be advisable.

Comment: context and localContext are just two variables pointing to the same instance of DBContext. So you cannot say they "share" something, or that they are "separate". There is only one context here, not two.

Comment: @Evk, so Reference Equality then? That's all I was asking. I can't find any documentation anywhere on the behaviour of .Equals for DBContexts, hence the question. I couldn't see any reason *why* someone would do what the previous architect had done if it wasn't value equality.

Comment: Well all classes (not structs) use reference equality by default, unless class author somehow changed this behavior. But there is no sense at all to use value equality for DbContext, cannot imagine what that might even mean. And there is absolutely no sense to copy variable in the code snippet you provided.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Do Contexts use Reference equality, meaning that context and localContext above will share the same additions, and saving one will commit changes on the other?

These are not two contexts, these are two references to the same context. Contexts are reference types, not value types. When `SaveChanges` is called, it is called on one and only the context. It doesn't matter if you reference it from `localContext` or `context`.

> 2. If I have two existing separate contexts, and I save one, will the changes be automatically picked up in the new context on any future query, or does a context "cache" at the point that it is created (pretty sure the answer to this is the former, but just want to clarify)?

It's not entirely clear what you mean with "cache" and "picking up the changes". There is no caching of entities, there is just change tracking of the entity objects the context knows about. Change tracking occurs on a per context basis, which means when you actually do have two independent contexts, saving in one context updates the tracked objects of this context. The other context remains unaffected by those changes, since it does not know about the first context's objects.

> 3. Is the code snippet above bad practice? I can't think of any circumstance where it would be advisable.

This question can not be answered universally. If there is only one context involved and if both `context` and `localContext` are never changed after the assignment, the code makes no sense and is at least confusing (it confused you, which proves the point). There are however other cases, where such an assignment would make sense, for example when there are multiple contexts involved and `localContext` can be either one of them.